# Network Ports on server state "media state authentication failed"

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have a server running Windows Server 2008 Enterprise in a 2k3 domain.  Only two Ethernet ports are active with static IP addresses assigned to each.  Even though the interfaces are issuing that error, I still have full LAN and WAN access.  I do not have any errors logged in the Event Logs.  Any help would be greatly appreciated from this new Server Fault user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help guys.  Apparently the network drivers Dell provided for the R710 needed to be installed without a network cable plugged into them.  For some reason the driver installs, restarts the port, and then finishes the installation.  So, unless in the split second you disabled the port, it attempted to allocate an IP from DHCP and then canceled.  Thereby botching the driver install.  The is for Broadcom drivers for Dell PowerEdge R710's.

Answer (score 0):

After googling it seems that is is related to IEEE 802.1x, have you tried to disable IEEE 802.1x authentication for your interfaces?

Comment: I did see that when I was doing the search engine research.  I enabled it and the error went away.  However, the question still stands why this is happening to all the 2k8 servers in our domain and not the other 50+ that run 2k3.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Do you by any chance have the option that is for the life of me escaping me right now, but is something along the lines of Enable Ieee 802.1x authentication enabled? I am sure it used to be found on the properties of the network card under authentication or somewhere, but I can't find it.